# Spanish characters in SQL select

Tags: sql-server-2008, character-encoding, html

I'm working on a Spanish language website where some text is stored in a MS SQL 2008 database table.

The text is stored in the db table with characters such as á, í and ñ.

When I retrieve the data, the characters don't display on the page.

This is probably a very simple fix but please educate me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Unicode instead of ANSI strings and functions, and must choose a web page encoding that has the required character set. Some searches on those terms will yield all you need. Look up content type 1252 and 8859 as well in case you get stuck (examples, not answers).

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid I had to change something to the database but all I needed was to use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` on the webpage

Comment: Good way to run with the ball and find the rest of the information yourself.

Comment: @greener: P.S. setting the content-type on the web server is best practice—doing it with the meta tag is not. If you are using dynamic pages you can do it in code. Otherwise, your web server setup (such as IIS manager) can set the content-type site-wide.